# kernel of a linear transformation and the kernel of its restriction

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider ${T: V \rightarrow W}$ to be a linear transformation between vector spaces. Let ${w}$ be a vector in ${W}$ and let ${U}$ be a subspace of ${W}$. Consider the restriction of ${T}$ to ${T^{-1}[U]}$. In general, I would think that the kernel of ${T}$ and the kernel of the restriction of ${T}$ to a smaller subset of the domain ${T^{-1}[U]}$ are not equal. Intuitively, the kernel of ${T}$ should be larger than that of its restriction. However, according to a solution posted by my teacher, they are the same. I am wondering why that's the case? Has it got to do with the fact that this subspace is the preimage of a subspace of the codomain? I do know that ${T^{-1}[T(v)] = v + Ker(T)}$.

Comment: So you have it: $\ker T \subset U$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I just edited the qn

Comment: I don’t see any relevant edit. Look at your last sentence and at my comment.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I got!

Comment: Looks like your confusion is caused by forgetting the fact that $kerT$ is also a vector subspace..